# PyTorch - Basic math operations on different shaped numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

1:
I have two numpy arrays with different shapes, I intent to get the mean squared error from the resulting operation. The numpy arrays are of different shapes, as part of the training, I have a validation set separate from the prediction numpy array, but the prediction set was built from the numpy array.

2:
I have tried to use torch.Tensor.repeat() as a way to enlarge the the prediction set, but I lack the correct math to do the repeat efficiently.

3:
the training method:

```
def train(net, x_train, x_opt, BATCH_SIZE, EPOCHS, input_dim):
    outputs = 0
    mse = 0
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
    loss = 0
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        for i in tqdm(range(0, len(x_train), BATCH_SIZE)):
           
            batch_y = x_opt[i:i + BATCH_SIZE]
            
            net.zero_grad()
            
            outputs = net(batch_y)
            
            loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()  # Does the update

        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}. Loss: {loss}")
        
    outputs = torch.Tensor.repeat(outputs, *****....***?, 1)
    return np.mean(np.power(x_opt - outputs.data.numpy(), 2), axis=1)
```

4:
the error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (92334,10) (46,10)

Comment: Maybe slice `outputs` the same way? E.g. `outputs[i: i + BATCH_SIZE]`? But I don't understand what you are actually going for, why do you use repeat, what's the task?

Comment: the goal does get lost in the number one section, but I am converting some tensorflow code to pytorch (for research) and I am trying to get the mean squared error to generate a threshold value.

Comment: though on this before, and it works, it feels like a short cut, but my time on this project is coming down to the wire, so it will have to do for now.

Comment: Can you explain which tensor/array has what shape?

Comment: the validation set (x_opt) is the 92334,10 and the output is 46,10

Comment: So your error is being thrown by the very last line, in the return statement? If so, maybe a padded broadcasting could be done.

Comment: I'll look it up, any examples or docs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a broadcast between the two if you pad the bigger one to a shape that is divisible by the smaller shape.

```
def pad_to_divisible_shape(arr, a_r, b_r):
    div = int(np.ceil(a_r/b_r))
    p = div*b_r-a_r
    return np.pad(arr, ((0,p),(0,0))), div

def broadcast_op(a, b):
    """Where a and b are numpy arrays and a.shape[0]>b.shape[0]"""
    a_r, b_r = a.shape[0], b.shape[0]
    a, div = pad_to_divisible_shape(a, a_r, b_r)
    a, b = a.reshape(div, b_r, -1), b.reshape(1, b_r, -1)
    return ((((a-b).reshape(-1, a.shape[-1]))**2).mean(axis=1))[:a_r]

a = np.random.randn(92334,10)
b = np.random.randn(46, 10)
out = broadcast_op(a,b)
```

Here a is padded from (92334,10) to (92368,10). Then a and b are reshaped as (2008,46,10) and (1,46,10), after which the operation a-b can be broadcasted. The actual output has the shape (92368,), from which you can simply remove the extra part by slicing [:a_r].